# For the cytoscape-fcose demo (constraint) demo, is it possible to set a constraint with n8?

Tags: cytoscape.js

The demo is located at:

https://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-fcose/demo/demo-constraint.html

The n8 node appears to be a compound node...?

I wanted to set a constraint using it. The constraint would be to make sure that the n2 was always above it. However, this does not appear to be possible.

Is it possible to set constraints using compound nodes?